# Visual Studio crashes when debug tests are run with the Test Result view in another screen

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, multiple-monitors

When I try to run unit tests, in debug mode only, on "Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2008 SP1" and the Test Results view is open in a screen other than the main one (I have 2 monitors), the devenv.exe process crashes. Have you ever encountered a similar error? Have you found a workaround for it?

Comment: I confirm the problem. The same in VS2010. I debugged VS2010 and it turned out that there is overflow in *clr.dll*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not heard of that issue before.  It would be great if you could file a bug with Visual Studio Connect on the issue.

- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Customer bugs, especially easily reproducible ones, are taken very seriously and it will be looked at.

Also would you mind posting back in the comments what the ID of the bug is?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved for my scenario: it was a reference issue. With Fusion assembly bind logging fully turned on, I found (having recently moved, again, from x86 to x64) that libraries I was referencing in a web.config were strong-named when compiled for x86, but when I recompiled them for Any CPU or x64, I hadn't used strong naming and therefore had a null PublicKeyToken. So assemblies that were in fact deployed, weren't being found by name by the framework at runtime.

Bad references/assembly bind issues/config file issues seem to be a real sticking point around .NET -- lots of potential for crashing and burning with little or no direct feedback, little or nothing useful ending up in the Event Log.